# Rename [airbus-a300-beluga] tag to [airbus-beluga]?

Tags: support, retagging

Currently, we have the [airbus-a300-beluga](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/airbus-a300-beluga) tag for questions about the [Airbus Beluga](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Airbus_Beluga) outsize-cargo aircraft.

Problem: we now have [at least two](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/71619/what-is-the-maximum-unloaded-range-of-the-beluga-xl) [questions](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/34763/why-is-the-airbus-beluga-xl-based-upon-the-a330-and-not-upon-the-a350-or-a380)<sup>1</sup> about the [Beluga *XL*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Airbus_Beluga_XL) (the original Beluga's intended successor), which is derived from the A330, not the A300, making [airbus-a300-beluga](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/airbus-a300-beluga) an obviously-inaccurate tag (due to the "A300" contained in the tag name) for these questions.  However, the Beluga XL's configuration, mission, etc., are so similar to those of the original Beluga that it doesn't really make sense to have two separate tags for the two; in fact, the Beluga XL is itself mentioned (and briefly described, and its Wikipedia article linked to), for completeness's sake, in the tagwiki for the aforementioned tag.

As such, we have a situation where the aircraft forming the subject of these questions is covered by (and described in the tagwiki of) a tag that, due solely to its name, cannot actually be *used* on these questions.  Renaming said tag to simply [airbus-beluga](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/airbus-beluga) would allow it to be used for questions concerning the Beluga XL, without introducing any significant amount of ambiguity in the process.

Could we rename the [airbus-a300-beluga](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/airbus-a300-beluga) tag to [airbus-beluga](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/airbus-beluga)?

---

<sup>1</sup>: Plus [a third](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/65209/airbus-beluga-what-is-aft-of-the-cockpit) that explicitly concerns *both* the original Beluga *and* the XL.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am with the rename to [airbus-beluga](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/airbus-beluga) for both planes.

While they have separate encyclopedic entries on Wikipedia, so do the different 737 families.

What made up my mind is Airbus' own website. The hyperlink to the XL in this [2019 news article](https://www.airbus.com/newsroom/news/en/2019/03/belugaxl-loadmaster-responsibilities.html) goes to [the same Beluga page for both](https://www.airbus.com/aircraft/freighter/beluga.html).

Comment: Different generations of 737s are still 737s, though. This isn't just different generations of the same airplane, but rather entirely different airplanes.

Comment: @reirab: I agree they're different planes. But one can [argue the same for the 737s](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/a/55039/14897). So thematically (topic; tag), I think one tag is enough for the Belugas.

Comment: Maybe someone with the ability to do so should just be bold and rename the tag?  If it turns out to be _that_ controversial a move, we can always hash it out later.

Comment: @Sean: Only the mods can, and there is (IMO) a backlog of tag-related requests. I'll ask for you in chat.

Comment: @Sean: It's been done.

Answer (score 0):

Personally, I would think that the Beluga and the Beluga XL should have separate tags. They are designed for similar missions, but they are not the same airplane or even in the same family of airplanes. I don't think one airplane being the successor to another to fill a given mission is grounds for those airplanes sharing a tag.

That being said, I don't have a particularly strong opinion whether the tags end up being [airbus-beluga](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/airbus-beluga) and [airbus-beluga-xl](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/airbus-beluga-xl) or [airbus-a300-beluga](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/airbus-a300-beluga) and [airbus-a330-beluga-xl](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/airbus-a330-beluga-xl).

Comment: I just don't think there are enough questions about either Beluga to warrant two tags. If one wants to be specific he could tag both Beluga *and* A300 or A330. I think if I wanted to look up questions about either of those it wouldn't come up with a huge number of responses.

Answer (score 0):

Since tags are topics/themes, I'd like to propose an alternative that I think is a good compromise:

[airbus-belugas](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/airbus-belugas) (plural): the Airbus Beluga-named beluga-shaped model**s**.